# Software for 3D vectors drawing

Tags: 3d

I need a software to draw vectors (line with an arrow) in 3D. Also I need to show angles between them, draw lines and simple objects for my paper. Can somebody advise me a good simple (mb not simple, but with good tutorial to understand it quickly) software?

Comment: To actually draw a 3D arrow and the arrowhead to show up properly is not a trivial task.

Comment: Look at GeoGebra!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending how much programming/interactivity you're after, take a look at:

- [3D Vector Drawer](http://www.erobo.net/online_store.php?product_id=105) (C#)
- [Open Inventor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Inventor) (C++)
- [MayaVi](https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/wiki/Mayavi/Gallery) (Python/Numpy/Scipy)
- [Sketch](http://www.frontiernet.net/~eugene.ressler/) (Latex world)
- [Gnuplot](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/) (has some 3D capabilities)